# How to search in MySQL for string without defined characters?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have stored unique identifiers within a MySQL 5.7.25 table, those are CHAR and contain dots and slashes.

Now I would need to search for them without those characters.

e.g.: Known string: 25518000

Within table: 255.18.000

Seems like preg_replace is only implemented in MySQL > 8.x.

How can I perform a search for a given string, ignoring certain characters?

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `cat_attr` WHERE `attr_de` REGEXP '\\.' = 25518000
```

Comment: You have no idea where in the strings the dots and slashes appear?  It's not a fixed pattern like xxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz?  There are no delimiters or spaces around the strings like { s } ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. I was thinking about something like this: preg_replace('/[^0-9A-Z]/', '', $v); or preg_replace('/\/|\./', '', $value['attr_name']) ! Is there something like this in MySQL?

Comment: You may face performance issues when searching through many records with suggested replaces. I'd recommend you to add another column (indexed) to the table where content with no such characters will be stored. You will need to add before insert/update triggers that will fill up the new column value.

Comment: Thank you for the warning. Good suggestion will keep in mind. For the prototype it’s OK for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is always dots, spaces, and slashes you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM cat_attr 
 WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(attr_de, '.', ''), '\\', ''), ' ', '') = 25518000;
```

For an example, this returns true:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('11\ 11.1', '.', ''), '\\', ''), ' ', '') = 11111;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! It is sometimes a space as third unwanted character. How can I add the empty character string? This apears to be wrong:  WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(attr_de, '.', ''), '\\', '', ' ', '') = 25518000

Comment: You can make it `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(attr_de, '.', ''), '\\', ''), ' ', '') = 25518000`. As long as those are the only 3 characters you want removed it should work. Not quite a pretty as the 8.x regex functions but it should get the job done.

Comment: That's strange. I just tried that exact syntax in a sandbox and it ran fine.

Comment: The syntax in your first comment here is different from what I suggested. You need to call the REPLACE function a third time rather than adding more parameters to the last one.

Comment: You are a geniuos! Thank you, that worked excellent and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to your server, you could use a user defined function (UDF) like

[mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp) or [mysql_udf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg).

Comment: I do have access. Would that mean to compile again? It is an ubuntu LTS install of MySQL 5.x